# Lambert's cosine law in 3D, why $\cos\theta$ instead of $\cos^2\theta$?

Tags: geometry, radiometry

I'm reading the book [An Invitation to 3-D Vision](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-21779-6) and I don't understand a part of the explanation regarding the "basic radiometric image formation model".

[image]

Looking at the Wikipedia page of the [Lambert's cosine law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert%27s_cosine_law) I can understand why in 2D the foreshortened area of $dA_p$ (let's call it $dW_q$, not present in the image above taken from the book) as seen from $q$ is $\cos\theta dA_p$. What I don't understand is why this relationship holds in 3D (as in the image where $dA_p$ is the area of a circle).

Here in the image for me is true that the diameter of $dW_q$ = $\cos\theta$ times the diameter of $dA_p$ for the same reason why in the Wikipedia page we have $d\Omega_0 -> d\Omega_0\cos\theta$. But if there is this relation between the diameters (and then the radii) we should have $dW_q = \cos^2\theta dA_p$ given that $dW_q = \pi R_W^2 = \pi (cos\theta R_A)^2 = \cos^2\theta dA_p$ where $R$ are the radii.

In the book $dW_q = \cos\theta dA_p$ and $d_{w_q} = \frac{\cos\theta dA_p}{d(p, q)^2}$, I would square both cosines.

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is the assumption that, as you increase $\theta$, the circle $dA_p$, as viewed from $dA_q$, shrinks isotropically, remaining a circle. But in fact, only one direction of it shrinks: the one in the plane of rotation, while the perpendicular size remains the same. The circle becomes an ellipse. Thus, we only multiply by $\cos\theta$ once, to account for the one direction in which the circle shrinks.

Comment: Thanks Ruslan, now my conceptual error is clear to me!